# Accessing debug registers on Windows 7 x64

Tags: winapi, windows-7-x64

I want to detect possible hardware breakpoints on my application. To do this I need read access to debug registers. Direct access is not possible so I do this in this way:

```
HANDLE thread = GetCurrentThread();

WOW64_CONTEXT context;
context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
BOOL status = Wow64GetThreadContext(thread, &context);

if (!status)
    return -1;

std::cout << std::hex << context.Dr0 << " " << context.Dr1 << " " << context.Dr2 << " " << context.Dr3 << " " << std::endl;
```

What I see on stdout is: **cccccccc cccccccc cccccccc cccccccc** even if there are hw breakpoints set by me.

Do I need some special permissions to access those registers? The application is 32 bit but I'm working on Windows 7 x64 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong ContextFlags value, you need CONTEXT_ALL to include CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS.

Answer (score 0):

quoting [MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20141213104218/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681665(v=vs.85).aspx):
If you call Wow64GetThreadContext for the current thread, the function returns successfully; however, the context returned is not valid.